# Upgrade to ASP.NET MVC version 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, upgrade

I have been doing some work on a ASP.NET MVC project today i tried to publish the website but i ve got an error. my hosting service provider told me is due to the fact that i have version 1 while they support version 2.
how can i upgrade to version 2?
are the differences between the two version so extreme that a previous version is not supported by the successuve?

thanks

Comment: Voting to close as too localized - this question was asked in reference to a prerelease version of MVC 2, and the final release has been out for a while now.

Comment: @Daniel -- I still find this helpful and upvoted one of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

That seems very unusual, because:

1. MVC 2 is still in beta, and
2. The two versions can be run side by side.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds backwards (i.e. I would see if they only supported 1, not 2).  2 is not yet final, unless I'm very much wrong.

MVC should be bin-deployable.  Just mark the reference (to your current v1 ref) to copy local and try publishing that way.

Comment: could you explain please
MVC should be bin-deployable. Just mark the reference (to your current v1 ref) to copy local and try publishing that way.

Comment: He means that, in your project references there is a reference to `System.Web.Mvc`, and in the properties for that reference is a property called `Copy Local.`  Set that to `true`.

Comment: Open the References node in Solution Explorer, find System.Web.Mvc, right click it and select Properties, set Copy Local to true. Then try publishing again.

Answer (score 1):

There is a guidance document on MSDN :[Upgrading an ASP.NET MVC 1.0 Application to ASP.NET MVC 2](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/1/6/F16F9AF9-8EF4-4845-BC97-639791D5699C/MVC2-Upgrade-Notes.pdf). I used it today and it was very helpful in migrating my application.