# Asp.net - MVC1 vs MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

can any one precisely explain the difference between ASP.NET MVC1 vs MVC2.. and if i'm having a project in MVC1, how can i migrate it to MVC2 ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829560/upgrade-to-asp-net-mvc-version-2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MVC 2 is a later version of the same library.

To upgrade to it, read [this page](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet-mvc2-upgrade-notes).

Comment: @Slaks, thank's buddy, i also wanna know from where can i get the source code for MVC 2, i mean previously microsoft was giving the source code for MVC 1 but now MVC 2 source is not available.

Comment: @FosterZ http://haacked.com/archive/2010/03/12/ms-pl-source-release-for-system-web-mvc-2.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is a conversion utility, see here: http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2010/03/10/migrating-asp-net-mvc-1-0-applications-to-asp-net-mvc-2-rtm.aspx