# What is the difference between ASP.Net MVC and ASP.Net MVC2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I've decided to take the suggestion from Robert Harvey on this site and build an application using ASP.Net MVC.

When I went to Bing for a brief overview, I saw there was an MVC2.

What is the difference and should I care?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447619/asp-net-mvc1-vs-mvc2

Comment: been asked many, many times before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVC2 is backwards compatible with MVC, so MVC2 is the one you will be using.

For the new features in version 2, see here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/11/asp-net-mvc-2-released.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just use MVC v2 if you have the option. It is an evolved version of MVC 1 with many useful enhancement. See [ASP.NET MVC 2 Released](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/11/asp-net-mvc-2-released.aspx)  for more info.